# Silverlight Datagrid binding with Object with a List Property

Tags: vb.net, silverlight

I'm having trouble with some Silverlight functionality.  My goal is to get some data from the database and display it in my grid.  Sounds simple, however, there are 7 columns that are always going to be there.
The rest of the columns depends on the account.  There could be 2 (called Actions) associated with a certain account, compared to another account that could have 5, and the action names can be completely different.
I have successfully been able to return a list of all the possible actions for the given account, and then adding the columns to the grid in the code bihind(VB), and I can bind my data to the grid for all the columns that 
are already known.  The way I store the item's actions, is a Property of type List.  My problem is finding a way to iterate through the actions list of the Item object in order to bind those actions to the grid.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create extension that will create additional columns and bindings that will bind each value from list to column. Also you should create an additional Dependency Property which you'll bind 
to your List.